# Angular ng-view not working properly

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am working through the mean-machine tutorial and have come to a road block when using ng-view to inject pages into the main layout. I have configured the routes in app.routes.js, defined the controllers in app.js, as well as created the html files for each page. Both app.js and app.routes.js have been loaded into the index.html file. mainController is working fine, just not the ancillary controllers. Please see the code below. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

public/views/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Routing App!</title>

  <!-- set the base path for angular routing -->
  <base href="/">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body { padding-top:50px; }
  </style>

  <!-- JS -->
  <!-- load angular and angular-route via CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- load our custom angular app files -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.routes.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container" ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">

  <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class ="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
  <main>

    <!-- angular templating will go here -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->

    <div ng-view></div>

  </main>

</body>
</html>
```

public/js/app.js

```
angular.module('routerApp', ['routerRoutes'])

// create the controllers
// this will be the controller for the ENTIRE site
.controller('mainController', function() {

  var vm = this;

  // create a bigMessage variable to display in our views
  vm.bigMessage = 'A smooth sea never made a skilled sailor.';
})

// home page specific controller
.controller('homeController', function() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.message = 'This is the home page!';
})

// about page controller
.controller('aboutController', function() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
})

// contact page controller
.controller('contactController', function() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

public/js/app.routes.js

```
// inject ngRoute for all our routing needs
angular.module('routerRoutes', ['ngRoute'])

// configure our routes
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
  .when('/', {
    templateURL: 'views/pages/home.html',
    controller: 'homeController',
    controllerAs: 'home'
  })

  // route for the about page
  .when('/about', {
    templateURL: 'views/pages/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })

  // route for the contact page
  .when('/contact', {
    templateURL: 'views/pages/contact.html',
    controller: 'contactController',
    controllerAs: 'contact'
  });

  // set our app to have pretty URLS
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

public/views/pages/home.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Home Page</h1>

  <p>{{ home.message }}</p>
</div>
```

public/views/pages/about.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>About Page</h1>

  <p>{{ about.message }}</p>
</div>
```

public/views/pages/contact.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Contact Page</h1>

  <p>{{ contact.message }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your templateURL properties have the right value? Try with `public/views/pages/home.html` or any full URL that shows up when you browse to your application in your browser.

See the documentation on the $routeProvider : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider.

Comment: I tried that - it didn't make a difference. I actually found the root of the problem, in the app.routes.js file, I wrote templateURL instead of templateUrl. I was going crazy there for a second, thanks for looking into it!